# Can not get a reference to ConfigurationManager

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, configurationmanager

I simply can not get Visual Studio 2005 to find the *System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager* class. Here is the code:

```
using System.Configuration;

...

x = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MySetting"]
// The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

x = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"]
// The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the
// namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I absolutely, positively **do** have a reference to *System.Configuration* in the project and it is definitely in the **right** project. The DLL is version 2.0.0.0 and the runtime version is 2.0.50727 - exactly the same as all the others. I have tried removing the reference and re-adding it. One strange thing is that when it is displayed in the References 'folder' of the project, it is displayed as 'System.configuration' - with a lower case 'c'.

Visual Studio can find the *System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings* class with no problem other than the warning that it is obsolete. The project is a web project and the code is in the code-behind of a WebControl.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowercase "c" in the reference is normal.  Your code works for me just fine.  I wonder if there's a problem outside of the snippet you've shown us.  Try building a brand-new solution with just a call to reference its configuration.  Prove that that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Turns out that the .NET runtime was all messed up because the account it was installed with did not have enough rights. A full re-install with a 'god' account fixed the problem. Very weird.

Answer (score 13):

Did you add a reference to the System Assembly System.Configuration.dll?

IIRC AppSettings is in the BCL core library, 2.0 ConfigurationManager is in separate assembly.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. The fact that VS2005 seemed to know about the System.Configuration namespace threw me off. Once I added the reference to the System.Configuration.dll then the ConfigurationManager became available. Thanks!